# Failed to decode downloaded font - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, icons, bower, font-awesome

I am working with a template that serves up font icons (font-awesome and simple-line-icons) through bower via `vendor/assets/bower_components`

Recently they've stopped working in production and the console error message I get is:

> Failed to decode downloaded font

And this is fired on page load:

> 301 - files have been permanently moved

I can't figure out why as I have not touched them - they were setup by default thanks to the template.

The file structure within the bower components looks like so:

```
--fontawesome
 --css
  --font-awesome.css
  --font-awesome.css.map
  --font-awesome.min.css

--fonts
 --fontawesome-webfont.eot
 --fontawesome-webfont.svg
 --fontawesome-webfont.ttf
 --fontawesome-webfont.woff
 --fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

The `font-awesome.css` file above contains:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The require in the `base.css.scss` file looks like so as you can see the reference path. This `base.css.scss` file is required in the `application.css.scss` file.

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into base.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
* 
* --- FontAwesome
*= require fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min
* --- Simple Line Icons
*= require simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons
* --- Animate.css
*= require animate.css/animate.min
* --- Whirl (spinners)
*= require whirl/dist/whirl
*
*/
```

The `application.rb` file includes:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
```

They work fine locally but don't in production (Heroku).

Also, I have this setup in my `gem` file:

```
group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

If you require anything else, please let me know. Any help would be huge.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for this?